# Show different field from table depending on job code

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm after some ideas on how I can write some Oracle SQL code to show a different field value depending on what the job_type_code is.

If the job_type_code is either EN11 or EN12 the only jobs that need to be returned are those where the target_comp_date is in the past.

If the job_type_code is either EN90 or EN91 all jobs should be displayed with the target_comp_date.

Code I've tried putting in is below.

```
select

case
 when job_type.job_type_code in ('EN11','EN12') and job.target_comp_date < SYSDATE then 
 job.target_comp_date
 when job_type.job_type_code in ('EN90','EN91') then job.target_comp_date
 else 'check'
 end as Test

from
job
inner join job_type on job.job_type_key = job_type.job_type_key
```

Comment: you will get a problem putting a either a date or a string in the same column.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `WHERE` clause here, not a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM job j
INNER JOIN job_type jt
    ON j.job_type_key = jt.job_type_key
WHERE
    (jt.job_type_code IN ('EN11', 'EN12') AND j.target_comp_date < SYSDATE) OR
     jt.job_type_code IN ('EN90', 'EN91');
```

Comment: thank you - of course it's a where statement and not a case. I'm looking to filter the data.

Answer (score 1):

A `case` expression in the `select` is not going to filter any data.  This sounds like a `where` clause:

```
where (job_type_code in ('EN11', 'EN12') and target_comp_date < sysdate
      ) or
      (job_type_code in ('EN90', 'EN91') and target_comp_date > sysdate
      )
```

It is not clear if you want other `job_type_codes`.  If so, add `or (job_type_code not in ('EN11', 'EN12', 'EN90', 'EN91')`.

Comment: thank you - of course it's a where statement and not a case. I'm looking to filter the data.